# SVN update everything else except for my branch

Tags: svn, merge

I want to do an SVN update of my current files.

Everything is from a previous user and it's out of date, except that their branch is the most current for that branch (so I want to keep their branch code).

How can I get the most recent of all the other files (outside of thir branch) but then commit their branch (since their branch is the most recent of "their branch")?

Comment: Could you elaborate?  You want to get uncommitted changes from a branch in someone else's working copy?  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to commit just their branch, and then update everything. You do know you can commit parts of your working copy?

If you're using TortoiseSVN, then you can commit everything, but un-check all the non-branch files in the dialog that appears.

Or you can just manually copy the branch code elsewhere, update everything, then copy the branch code back. Kludgy but its easy to understand and it just works.

And as SVN has the concept of sparse directories you can 'remove' directories from your working copy that you're not interested in anymore (by doing an update to revision on those directories and setting the depth to 'exclude').